# No Sustainsys.Saml2 for MVC 3? Are there any alternatives?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, single-sign-on, saml-2.0

I have a requirement to update my ADFS configuration as the client is now changing product and would like us to use SAML 2.0.

My application is still in MVC 3 and I cannot upgrade without spending a significant amount of time in doing so (Writing a new application might be easier and quicker)

Can anyone please recommend an open source library, or point me in the right direction of how to achieve this?

One of the problems I have is that currently it is trying to communicate via WS-FED instead of SAML, is there a way to change this?

Thanks for any help people can give.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a list of SAML stacks, look [here](https://medium.com/the-new-control-plane/i-need-a-saml-stack-now-63d9691e2d43).

I'm guessing your application is built using WIF which only allows WS-Fed.

There is no Microsoft replacement SAML stack for this.

Basically, rip out WIF and add SAML.

Comment: Thanks, I went with AspNetSaml as I only need the basic redirect and authenticate.